# Go to the next page of paper in print if reach the given maximum height of the element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possile with CSS / jQuery to know if the certain `div` reaches its maximum capacity to store elements. For sample check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz94q2ko/). I want when the continuation go to the next page is will still print the header I made.

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <h1> Header 1 </h1>
   <p>If this paragraph reaches the maximum of height of the div the continuation should be on the next page
    If this paragraph reaches the maximum of height of the div the continuation should be on the next page
    If this paragraph reaches the maximum of height of the div the continuation should be on the next page
    If this paragraph reaches the maximum of height of the div the continuation should be on the next page
    If this paragraph reaches the maximum of height of the div the continuation should be on the next page   
    </p>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: next page of paper in printing updated my question.